# Testing async DOM/CSS changes with Jasmine 2 - migrating from waitsFor to done()

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am currently updating the test suite for a popover / tooltip library of mine from Jasmine 1.3 to Jasmine 2.

The library operates in a mostly asynchronous fashion, since it makes extensive use of CSS transitions. For example,

1. you `.show()` a tooltip,
2. it starts the CSS transitions,
3. waits for them to complete and
4. then if necessary, repositions the tooltip after it is layouted and fully visible.

Because of this, a large portion of my specs currently take this form:

```
it("should update the CSS classes after repositioning the tooltip due to lack of space", function() {
  var popoverIsVisible = false;

  // instantiate a popover with specific settings
  runs(function() {
    instance = new Popover(domElement, {position: "left center", alternativePositions: ["right center"]});

    instance.addCallback('afterShow', function() { popoverIsVisible = true; });

    instance.show();
  });

 // the afterShow callback is run after the CSS transitions 
 // have run and the tooltip is visible
  waitsFor(function() {
    return popoverIsVisible;
  }, "The afterShow callback should have triggered", 100);

  runs(function() {
    expect(instance.popover().hasClass('horizontal-right')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It seems to me that in order to transition to the `done()` callback style of Jasmine 2, I would have to wrap *each and every spec* in its own `describe` block and move the library setup part into `beforeEach`:

```
describe("...", function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    var instance = new Popover(domElement, {position: "left center", alternativePositions: ["right center"]});

    instance.addCallback('afterShow', function() { done(); });

    instance.show();
  });

  it("should update the CSS classes when repositioning the tooltip due to lack of space", function() {
    expect(instance.popover().hasClass('horizontal-right')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Using one individual `describe` block and `beforeEach` per spec feels wrong to me, as if I am working against Jasmine. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to structure my specs?

Comment: Could you post some more code, please?

Comment: @toothbrush what seems to be missing?

Comment: Well, I wanted to see a couple of the specification blocks, so I could see what you meant.

Comment: Here is the full spec file: https://github.com/janfoeh/attachejs/blob/development/test/js/specs/attache-spec.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to have separate `describe`s/`beforeEach`s for each individual `it` you should also be able to just have your expectations in the callback for the asynchronous function, and call the `done` for the `it` after that. Something like:

```
describe("...", function() {
  it("should update the CSS classes when repositioning the tooltip due to lack of space", function(done) {
    var instance = new Popover(domElement, {position: "left center", alternativePositions: ["right center"]});

    instance.addCallback('afterShow', function() {
      expect(instance.popover().hasClass('horizontal-right')).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });

    instance.show();
  });
});
```

Because the `it` is asynchronous, jasmine will fail the test if it doesn't call the `done` callback in time, so your tests should appropriately fail if the callback from the asynchronous function is never invoked.

Comment: Thank you Gregg! In retrospect it seems rather obvious - no idea why I couldn't see the forest for the trees.